# Android string encryption stops before cipher.init() method

Tags: java, android, encryption, jce

I am creating an Android application that encrypts a string using a user-chosen password. The system will display the encrypted string in the edit text.

This is the method that I try to encrypt with. Can anyone tell me where is the error  that do not allow the system to show the result?

The system stops before the line `cipher.init()`.

**Log cat**

```
01-01 12:37:37.756: D/libEGL(2810): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-01 12:37:37.756: D/(2810): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8d1bce8, tid 2810
01-01 12:37:37.872: D/libEGL(2810): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-01 12:37:37.872: D/libEGL(2810): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-01 12:37:38.112: W/EGL_genymotion(2810): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-01 12:37:38.112: E/OpenGLRenderer(2810): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-01 12:37:38.180: E/OpenGLRenderer(2810): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-01 12:37:38.196: D/OpenGLRenderer(2810): Enabling debug mode 0
01-01 12:37:47.508: W/EGL_genymotion(2810): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-01 12:37:52.344: W/EGL_genymotion(2810): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-01 12:37:52.452: D/dalvikvm(2810): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 1% free 16924K/17072K, paused 14ms, total 16ms
01-01 12:37:56.420: E/PBEkEYsPEC(2810): javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec@52de0e0c
01-01 12:37:56.492: E/PBEkEYsPEC(2810): com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BCPBEKey@52e0076c
01-01 12:37:56.492: E/PBEkEYsPEC(2810): javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec@52e00df8
```

**Code**

```
public String Padding_key() {

  try {

    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(STReditTxtPass.toCharArray());
    Log.e("PBEkEYsPEC", pbeKeySpec.toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, "step 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    Toast.makeText(this, "after ciphering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
    .getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    Toast.makeText(this, "after keyFactory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    SecretKey pbeKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    Log.e("PBEkEYsPEC", pbeKey.toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, "after SecreteKey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    PBEParameterSpec pbeSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations);
    Log.e("PBEkEYsPEC", pbeSpec.toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, "after PBEParameterSpec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeSpec);

    Toast.makeText(this, "after cypher.init", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(PlainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "after byte[]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    cyphertext = String.format("%s%s%s", toBase64(salt), "]",
    toBase64(cipherText));
    Toast.makeText(this, "after cypherText.format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    edit_txt_enc_string.setText(cyphertext);

    strPaddingencryption = edit_txt_enc_string.getText().toString();

  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
  return strPaddingencryption;
}
```

Comment: Can you not trace through it on a debugger

Comment: i added a lot of logs and toast to know what is happening but still can not get the result  so can anyone help me i need this solution   and sorry for the confused coding

Comment: I would strongly recommend you add a `e.printStacktrace()` to your `catch` clause - you might be missing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to perform password-based encryption. If that is the case, your error is likely caused by using `"AES"` as the algorithm in your `Cipher` object. Try this instead:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
```

Please also note that `PBEWithMD5AndDES` is very weak by modern standards. If you have any control over the algorithm used, please switch to something stronger. For instance, you could use `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` to produce a key that you then use with AES to encrypt the plaintext.

See [the code](https://code.google.com/p/jncryptor/source/browse/trunk/jncryptor/src/main/java/org/cryptonode/jncryptor/AES256v2Cryptor.java) for my project, JNCryptor, for an example of how this is done in Java.